# Django-Storages - I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, python-django-storages

I am trying to upload file in Amazon S3 Bucket. For that purpose I have installed latest version of Django-Storages.

Though media is getting serve from S3 bucket but I am unable to upload file to S3 bucket'. I get this error:

```
Value error: I/O operation on closed file
```

I read over here https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/382 that this issue is cause of django-storages version. I changed version to 1.6.0 then I started getting error:

```
No module named 'django.utils.six'
```

Then I changes django version and more errors start getting appear and so on.
My first question: Does this I/O error is really due to just django-storages version? If that so, then how to cater this situation as I was using most upgraded version of everything?